# How to avoid Restricted Scopes OAuth verification process for private scripts used only by me?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have received email from Google with subject: [Action Required] Submit your app(s) for Restricted Scopes OAuth verification,
same as many of you.

I'm using GAS only for developing applications for my personal use - not for public. Applications such as sending summary emails to my clients, when they buy a product from my web pages.

- Do I have to go through the whole process of verification?
- Do I have to create public Terms of Service?
- Is there any way how I can explain to google, that my applications are not used by anybody else then by
  me?
- How to get to know for sure that my app won't stop?

I have read through FAQ (https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914) and many other documents by google about this topic..

I have checked similar questions found on web, but with no luck of answers.. It looks it's pretty new experience for all of us..
Thank you for any advices.

I have personal account, so I can't use "internal apps" selection, this works only for paid G-suite customers which I'm not.

**EDIT:**

As Yoel Vinitsky stated, app doesn't need verification if it has only one user.

Here at bottom: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865 is table which shows that there is *quota 100 new users in total, once the app presents the unverified app screen*.

It seems like that I don't have to worry about verification of my apps at all, because I'm the only one user or maybe I use this app from 2 or 3 more users emails so it should be ok, my question is, **is it going to be ok without verification, or not?**

**EDIT 2:**
Google sent clarification email:

*NO ACTION is required if:
Only owners use the project: If the project is only used by owners of the project, no action is required.*

*To determine whether you are an owner (versus an editor or viewer), follow these steps:*

1. *Click the project link above to navigate to its OAuth Consent Screen
   configuration page.*
2. *Click the Navigation Menu button in the
   upper-left corner, select IAM & admin, and click IAM. This will show you all project contributors and their roles.*

*The project doesn’t have users outside of your G Suite domain:If the project owner is using a G Suite account and the project is only used by Google Accounts in the project owner’s domain, no action is required (learn more here).*

**But the question is how to avoid verification with *personal* accounts for my own scripts used only by me?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the support FAQ You linked to:

When can I skip publishing my app for a review?

```
You do not need to request for verification if your app is
```

going to be used in any of the following scenarios:

```
1) The app is not shared with anyone else.
2) The app is used to send emails through WordPress, or
3) similar single account SMTP plug-ins.
```

The only drawbacks should be the warning that your app is unverified and maybe quota limits.

Comment: Hi, do you have practical experience with those quotas? I have edited my question after more studying this quotas topic.

Comment: As yet no. I am in the development phase of our first google script and never got close to quote limits.